# Call Python from MATLAB Operator Error for x**2

Tags: python, matlab, gekko

I'm calling a Python function from MATLAB but I'm running into an error:

```matlab
clear all
% Initialize model
m = py.gekko.GEKKO();
% Initialize Variable
x = m.Var();
% Define Equation
m.Equation(x**2+2*x+1==0);
% Solve
m.solve();
% Extract values from Python lists using curly brackets
disp(['x: ' num2str(x.VALUE{1})]);
```

```
Error: File: test_gekko3.m Line: 7 Column: 14
Invalid use of operator.
```

When I change it to `x^2` (MATLAB version of power), there is no error. If I'm calling a Python function, why does it require that I use a MATLAB operator in that function?

Comment: I don’t know about GEKKO but I guess you should pass a string to `m.Equation`. The way you wrote it there, the equation is being evaluated by MATLAB, not by Python and not by GEKKO.

Comment: I had to use the 'Raw' function in Gekko to pass in a string:
```x = m.Var(pyargs('name','x'));
m.Raw('Equations')
m.Raw('x^2+2*x+1=0');
```  I was mostly just curious if there is a way to force the argument to be evaluated by Python instead of MATLAB if it is a Python function.

Comment: I found another way to have it evaluated as a Python string: ```x = m.Var(pyargs('name','x'));``` and ```m.Equation(pyargs('equation','x**2+2*x+1=0'));``` (replace the two corresponding lines). If you'd like to post this as an answer, I'll be glad to accept it. Thanks for the suggestion to pass in a string.

Comment: You should definitely post that as an answer. Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion from Cris Luengo to pass in the argument as a string. This is now interpreted as a Python expression instead of as a MATLAB expression. The following two methods now work in MATLAB.

**Method 1: Python Expression**

```matlab
clear all
% Initialize model
m = py.gekko.GEKKO();
% Initialize Variable
x = m.Var(pyargs('name','x'));
% Define Equation
m.Equation(pyargs('equation','x**2+2*x+1=0'));
% Solve
m.solve();
% Extract values from Python lists using curly brackets
disp(['x: ' num2str(x.VALUE{1})]);
```

In this case, naming the `x` variable is required because otherwise the variable has an internal name of `v1` and `x` wouldn't be allowed in the expression. The second method is easier.

**Method 2: MATLAB Expression**

```matlab
clear all
% Initialize model
m = py.gekko.GEKKO();
% Initialize Variable
x = m.Var();
% Define Equation
m.Equation(x^2+2*x+1==0);
% Solve
m.solve();
% Extract values from Python lists using curly brackets
disp(['x: ' num2str(x.VALUE{1})]);
```

Using the MATLAB expression is more compact and is more consistent with the other MATLAB code.